# JVMTI Encrypt&Decrypt Java class file

Tags: java, encryption, openssl, bytecode-manipulation, jvmti

I'm doing something to encrypt java .class file, and using jvmti agentlib to decrypt the source data. there always an Exception.

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Unknown constant tag 0 iin class file com/dxf/MethodTraceTest
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

My Environment: Windows7 64bit, JDK1.8.0_172 x64, visual studio 2017, OpenSSL-win64

decrypt function

```
int DEncrypter::Decrypte(int fileSize, const unsigned char* class_data, unsigned char* my_data)
{
    int data_lenth = 0;
    const int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;

    char data[BUFFER_SIZE];
    memset(data, 0, sizeof(data));

    int nLen = RSA_size(m_pRsaPrivate);

    //write decrypt class data in file
    FILE *fp;
    if ((fp = fopen("d:\\com\\dxf\\MethodTraceTest.class", "ab+")) == NULL) {
        printf("Open file error!");
        exit(0);
    }

    int uReadFileSize = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < nLen; i++) {
        data[i] = class_data[i];
    }

    while (uReadFileSize < fileSize)
    {
        int LastLength = (nLen);

        if ((fileSize - uReadFileSize) <= (nLen))
        {
            LastLength = (fileSize - uReadFileSize);
        }

        char *pDecode = new char[nLen];
        memset(pDecode, 0, nLen);

        //decrypt
        int Dret = RSA_private_decrypt(nLen, (const unsigned char *)data,
            (unsigned char *)pDecode, m_pRsaPrivate, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING);

        if (Dret >= 0)
        {
            data_lenth += Dret;

            //write file
            fwrite(pDecode, (Dret), 1, fp);

            for (int i = uReadFileSize, j = 0; j < nLen; j++, i++)
            {
                my_data[i] = pDecode[j];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Error: %s\n", ERR_reason_error_string(ERR_get_error()));
        }

        fseek(fp, 0, 2);

        uReadFileSize += nLen;

        //clear Buffer
        memset(data, 0, sizeof(data));
        delete[] pDecode;
        pDecode = NULL;

        for (int i = uReadFileSize, j = 0; j < nLen; j++, i++) {
            data[j] = class_data[i];
        }

    }
    fclose(fp);
    CRYPTO_cleanup_all_ex_data();
    RSA_free(m_pRsaPrivate);

    return data_lenth;
}
```

class file load hook

```
DEncrypter* dencrypter = new DEncrypter();
void JNICALL ClassLoadAgent::ClassLoadHook(jvmtiEnv *jvmti_env,
    JNIEnv* jni_env,
    jclass class_being_redefined,
    jobject loader,
    const char* name,
    jobject protection_domain,
    jint class_data_len,
    const unsigned char* class_data,
    jint* new_class_data_len,
    unsigned char** new_class_data
)
{
    *new_class_data_len = class_data_len; 

    jvmti_env->Allocate(class_data_len, new_class_data);

    unsigned char* my_data = *new_class_data;

    if (name && strncmp(name, "com/dxf/", 8) == 0)
    {
        printf("%s\n", name);

        int ret = dencrypter->Decrypte(class_data_len, class_data, my_data);

        *new_class_data_len = ret;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < class_data_len; ++i)
        {
            my_data[i] = class_data[i];
        }
    }
}
```

jvmti init

```
void ClassLoadAgent::Init(JavaVM *vm) const throw(AgentException){
    jvmtiEnv *jvmti = 0;
    JNIEnv* jni_env = 0;
    jint ret = (vm)->GetEnv(reinterpret_cast<void**>(&jvmti), JVMTI_VERSION);

    if (ret != JNI_OK || jvmti == 0) {
        throw AgentException(JVMTI_ERROR_INTERNAL);
    }

    m_jvmti = jvmti;
}
```

jvmti ParseOptions

```
void ClassLoadAgent::ParseOptions(const char* str) const throw(AgentException)
{
    if (str == 0)
        return;
    const size_t len = strlen(str);
    if (len == 0) 
        return;
}
```

jvmti add capability

```
void ClassLoadAgent::AddCapability() const throw(AgentException)
{
    jvmtiCapabilities caps;
    memset(&caps, 0, sizeof(caps));

    //caps.can_tag_objects = 1;
    caps.can_generate_all_class_hook_events = 1;
    //caps.can_generate_object_free_events = 1;
    //caps.can_get_source_file_name = 1;
    //caps.can_get_line_numbers = 1;
    //caps.can_generate_vm_object_alloc_events = 1;

    jvmtiError error = m_jvmti->AddCapabilities(&caps);
    CheckException(error);
}
```

jvmti register event

```
void ClassLoadAgent::RegisterEvent() const throw(AgentException)
{
    dencrypter->InitDEncrypter();
    dencrypter->OpenPrivateKeyFile("RSA_PrivateKey.key", "123456");

    jvmtiEventCallbacks callbacks;
    memset(&callbacks, 0, sizeof(callbacks));

    callbacks.ClassFileLoadHook = &ClassLoadAgent::ClassLoadHook;

    jvmtiError error;
    error = m_jvmti->SetEventCallbacks(&callbacks, static_cast<jint>(sizeof(callbacks)));
    CheckException(error);

    error = m_jvmti->SetEventNotificationMode(JVMTI_ENABLE, JVMTI_EVENT_CLASS_FILE_LOAD_HOOK, NULL);

    CheckException(error);
}
```

Agent OnLoad

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Agent_OnLoad(JavaVM *vm, char *options, void *reserved)
{
    cout << "Agent_OnLoad(" << vm << ")" << endl;
    try{

        agent = new ClassLoadAgent();
        agent->Init(vm);
        agent->ParseOptions(options);
        agent->AddCapability();
        agent->RegisterEvent();

    } catch (AgentException& e) {
        cout << "Error when enter Agent_OnLoad: " << e.what() << " [" << e.ErrCode() << "]";
        return JNI_ERR;
    }

    return JNI_OK;
}
```

Comment: You’re doing something wrong.

Comment: I have write a .class file in my decrypt function.  I run the .class file in normal way. It work fine. So I don't know what should I do.

Comment: First, you could provide a more detailed description of what you are doing rather than “I'm doing something”. When you have tried to use your decrypt function in a different context, you made a good step in narrowing down the problem, but you have to document it in your question. Since this implies that the problem are located in the way you use jvmti, there is no way around showing how you are using jvmti.

Comment: I have add the code details in my answer.